# Schedulable Apex to send an email to opportunity owner

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I wish to send an email to an opportunity owner if a checkbox is true on the product object. This needs to be schedulable once daily. I've written the part about product and only pulling through records with the checkbox, now I need to get the opportunity owner, and send them an email.

```
global class OpOwnerOldService_Scheduled Implements Schedulable
    {
        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
        {
            sendEmailtoOppOwner();
        }

        public void sendEmailtoOppOwner()
        {
            List<OpportunityLineItem> listOpportunityLineItem = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
            listOpportunityLineItem = [SELECT ID FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Make_unavailable_for_opps_and_proposals__c = TRUE];

            for(OpportunityLineItem opp : listOpportunityLineItem)
            {
```

Comment: It seems you're missing the bottom half of your code- i suggest making an [edit] and adding it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with the bottom part of the code and that's what I need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a subquery as your filter condition.

```
SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id In (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Make_unavailable_for_opps_and_proposals__c = TRUE)
```

You can read more about using a subquery as a filter condition in [this related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13325/how-to-select-only-those-objects-that-have-child-relationship) and in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm).

---

Heres a snippet from the [OutBoundMessage Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm). It should act as a solid base to start writing your own email message apex.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

// Strings to hold the email addresses to which you are sending the email.
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'user@acme.com'}; 
String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {'smith@gmail.com'};

// Assign the addresses for the To and CC lists to the mail object.
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);

// Specify the address used when the recipients reply to the email. 
mail.setReplyTo('support@acme.com');

// Specify the name used as the display name.
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');

// Specify the subject line for your email address.
mail.setSubject('New Case Created : ' + case.Id);

// Specify the text content of the email.
mail.setPlainTextBody('Your Case: ' + case.Id +' has been created.');

mail.setHtmlBody('Your case:<b> ' + case.Id +' </b>has been created.<p>'+
     'To view your case <a href=https://***yourInstance***.salesforce.com/'+case.Id+'>click here.</a>');

// Send the email you have created.
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```